# Delphi EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError Exception - SSL3_GET_RECORD Wrong Version Number

Tags: delphi, multipartform-data, firemonkey, tls1.2, indy

I tried using `TRESTClient` to connect to an HTTPS web service using TLS 1.2. But NO LUCK with sending `multipart/form-data`.

So now I am trying with Indy. I got this "Wrong Version Number" error.

I think there is nothing wrong with the code since it worked with HTTP.

Probably my Delphi is missing something. What should I install and how?

```pascal
procedure TForm10.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RequestBody: TStream;
  ResponseBody: string;
  myssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Input: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  ResponseBody := '';
  try
    try
      HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
      try
        Input := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
        try
          Input.Clear;
          Input.AddFormField('Email', 'xx@xx.com.tr');
          Input.AddFormField('Password', 'xx');

          myssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP);
          HTTP.IOHandler := myssl;
          myssl.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
          myssl.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
          myssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
          HTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];

          HTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
          ResponseBody := HTTP.Post('https://xxx.com.tr/api/Mobile/MobileLoginControl', Input);

        finally
          Input.Free;
        end;
      finally
        HTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
    end;
  except
    ResponseBody := '"-20"';
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine, though you are enabling *only* TLS 1.2 on the `SSLIOHandler`. Maybe the website in question doesn't support TLS 1.2? Try enabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 as well:

```
myssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
```

And don't set the `SSLOptions.Method` at all. Setting the `SSLVersions` updates the `Method` and vice versa. So set one or the other, not both.

Comment: Tried that now. I got 'ssl23_get_server_hello unknown protocol' error. I even put the port in my url address like 'xxx.com.tr:443' and the result is the same.

Comment: "unknown protocol" usually means OpenSSL received something that is not a valid server handshake. For instance, if you try to negotiate an SSL/TLS handshake on a port that is not using SSL/TLS. Have you tried sniffing the network traffic to see what the server is actually sending?

Comment: Actually I used a website to double-check what the server is using. It is using TLS1_2 and nothing else.
I checked my SSL version with IdSSLOpenSSL.OpenSSLVersion and saw that my version is 'OpenSSL 1.0.0g 18 Jan 2012'.
Should I upgrade? If yes, how? @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @RuhiGoktas yes, you need to upgrade OpenSSL as 1.0.0 is old. The latest version supported by Indy is 1.0.2 (support for 1.1.x is in the works). You can get newer DLLs from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL

Comment: I downloaded "openssl-1.0.2q-x64_86-win64.zip" from there. There were ssleay.ddl and libeay.dll in the zip, copied them to my Windows/System32 folder 
then checked the version again from the code, it didn't change.
(Same thing happened for Windows/SysWOW64 as well. How can I make Delphi recognize my SSL change?

Comment: @RuhiGoktas do not put the DLLs in the Windows System folders. They don't belong there. Put them in your app's folder instead.

Comment: I tried putting the DLLs in the app's folder (C:\Users\gurkan\Desktop\rest2\Win32\Debug). But it keeps showing my version the same. Is there any step I've missed?

Comment: @RuhiGoktas After the DLLs have been loaded, you can use the Win32 `GetModuleFileName()` function to find out exactly where they were actually loaded from (to get the DLL module handles, Indy has `GetSSLLibHandle()` and `GetCryptLibHandle()` functions, or you can use the Win32 `GetModuleHandle()` function). Either the DLLs you are using are not the right version you are expecting, or some other DLLs on your system are being loaded instead.